# ElasticBeanstalk not pinging worker HTTP path

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a ElasticBeanstalk worker tier app. But that EB is not pining the worker http path like it supposed to even though there is message in the SQS queue.

Message in the queue

```
{"job":"alert","data":[]}
```

Message configuration set in EB

```
MIME type application/json
```

HTTP path

```
/workers
```

Is there anything else that I need to configure. Policy for the group is following.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "MetricsAccess",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "QueueAccess",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
            "sqs:SendMessage"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "BucketAccess",
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DynamoPeriodicTasks",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*-stack-AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry*"
        ]
    }
 ]}
}
```

Comment: What port are you listening on? What do the logs say?

Comment: Log have no entry for workers ping that's the problem. Is in  port 80